# How to fix dark skin issue on SAMP class selection in pawn?

Tags: multiplayer, pawn, sa-mp

I'm working on a SAMP server using pawn language, but I've started facing an issue since I started work on SAMP player skin selection class. The issue is when a player request's a class all skins becomes darker.

### My Code:

```
public OnPlayerRequestClass(playerid, classid) {
    SetPlayerPos(playerid, 154.1271, -1951.8545, 51.3438);
    SetPlayerCameraPos(playerid, 148.6122, -1951.0000, 52.7962);
    SetPlayerCameraLookAt(playerid, 154.1271, -1951.8545, 51.3438);
    SetPlayerFacingAngle(playerid, -279.1916);
    return 1;
}
```

### Screenshot Of The Issue:

[image]

### Screenshot Of The Expected Results:

[image]

As you can see in the first screenshot the player skin is darker then normal.

### What I have tried:

I have tried rearranging the code, like calling `SetPlayerCameraPos()` before `SetPlayerPos()`.
I have also tried using a timer to add a delay before setting player pos and camera pos.
I have also tried using `TogglePlayerSpectating` method to make sure every things gets loaded with player's camera.
But still same result.

If you know any solution for this problem please share.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

This is a lighting effect that's caused by the weather Id of your environment - not the camera position.

You have two options:

Try changing the world time - using SetWorldTime() or SetPlayerTime
or change the weather using SetWeather() or SetPlayerWeather(). I'd suggest trying weather id 10.